# Suggestions on investigating a failure with writing RAW data to a USB drive

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have a 16GB USB drive from SanDisk (Cruzer Glide). I've purchased these before and had great success with them. The ones I bought previously had an amber LED. The new ones I bought have a blue LED. There are numbers on the back which differ between drives but the model itself is the same: `SDCZ60-016G`.

I noticed a problem today when trying to write a Linux image to the disk using a RAW write and having it either fail to verify during the pre-installation test or completely fail or boot. I tried several write attempts on two of these new blue LED drives and they all failed to verify.

The drives appear to be genuine and have passed a complete write and verify by `h2testw`, which I've used in the past to determine if an SD card is counterfeit. The test wrote and verified the entire disk without problem.

To confirm writing to the disk, I copied the Linux ISO I downloaded (1.5G), verified the sha256 hash locally, copied it to the USB disk, and verified it again there. Files are copying fine when done so on a formatted disk but appear to be failing when performing a RAW write.

I tried to write this ISO using UltraISO (Bootable -> Write Disk Image...) and Win32 Disk Imager. Both would write as RAW but failed to verify.

What can I do to further investigate what is being written to the disk to try and identify the problem?

I have been writing these images from Windows 10 x64 but have access and experience with Linux. So any suggestions on investigating this can be from either operating system.

---

Note that I do NOT have this problem with the older Cruzer Glides (with the amber LED). This is only a problem with the newer blue LED ones.

Comment: What's the actual message you get when they fail? What kind of failure are you seeing?

Comment: The errors are ambiguous. Either they fail to boot entirely or fail the verification (usually at around 4%). Win32 Disk Imager confirms that there was a problem when verifying, again, with a very early failure. There has never been a problem with writing the RAW image to the disk; it's only afterwards when reading or verifying the image where the fault becomes apparent.

Comment: Has ultraiso worked to make identical copies of ISO's before? It's not just extracting & copying files with a different format? Some live USB creators do that. How did you verify the ISO was copied to the USB, something like `sha256 /dev/sdx`, or read another copy with `dd if=/dev/sdx ...`?

Comment: @Xen2050 is capable of performing a RAW write.